# TileMap: How to convert MBTiles to RMaps SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, file-formats, mbtiles

These two map formats look very similar (based on SQLite and Tiled Maps).

I am looking for method to convert maps from mbtiles to RMaps SQLite and vice versa without quality lost.

Answer (score 1):

A reasonably easy to use GUI based tool for this is Mobile Atlas Creator:
http://mobac.sourceforge.net/
I've used it many times to do this very operation.

Just add your existing MBTiles file using "SQLite based atlas formats" instructions at the very bottom of the manual here:
http://mobac.sourceforge.net/MOBAC/README.HTM#FileBased

And create a new RMaps format output file. All it does is copy the tiles from one SQLite container to the other, so no loss of quality.

Answer (score 0):

You may use simple python converter:

https://github.com/tarwirdur/mbtiles2osmand

Comment: this converter do not address RMaps as I can understand it. The problem is also  that I have not been able to find  a description of RMaps format

Comment: @kFly osmand uses RMaps format. The converter based on manual analysis of RMaps file and mbtiles file. Also there is someone's gist on github (the second variant by jerome077 do the same as my python script): https://gist.github.com/andrewharvey/4516352